# Embedding of projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be the curve $x^2=yz$ in $P^2$, and $K=K(C)$ be its function field. Is it true that for any polynomial $t$ in $S[x,y,z]$, $k=k(t)$ is function field of $P^1$. It's not clear to me what $k(t)$ looks like?

Does it give an embedding for any $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conic $C\subset \mathbb P^2$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ through the isomorphism $$ \mathbb P^1 \stackrel {\cong}{\to} C: (u,v)\mapsto (x:y:z)=(uv:u^2:v^2)     $$
Since the function field of $\mathbb P^1$ is $k(\frac uv)=k(t)$ you can write in terms of the coordinates in $\mathbb P^2$ $$K(C)=k(\frac yx)=k(\frac xz)$$ However beware : it is false that, say,  $K(C)=k(\frac {y^2}{ x^2})$, even though the fields $k(\frac yx)$ and $k(\frac {y^2}{ x^2})$ are abstractly isomorphic extensions of $k$. You have to distinguish *isomorphism* from *equality* here!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use *Luroth's theorem*: every subfield of $k(X)$ which is not $k$ is isomorphic to $k(X)$.